# If $\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}$ is continuous, then there exists $c \in (0,\infty)$ such that $\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}(x) = \frac{c}{x^2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to solve the following problem from an old prelim exam:

Let $\lambda$ denote Lebesgue measure on $(0,\infty)$ and let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure such that $\mu \ll \lambda$ and $\mu(B) = \alpha \mu(\alpha B)$ for any $\alpha \in (0,\infty)$ and any Borel set $B \subset (0,\infty)$. If $\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}$ is continuous, then there exists $c \in (0,\infty)$ such that $\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}(x) = \frac{c}{x^2}$.

I don't have any idea about how to approach this problem.

Comment: I think you want to allow $c=0$ as well. Take $\mu$ equal the zero measure, then you also need $c=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}(x)$. Then we get for any Borel set $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and any $\alpha>0$
$$ \int_B f(x) dx = \mu(B) = \alpha \mu(\alpha B) = \alpha \int_{\alpha B} f(x)dx = \int_B \alpha^2 f(\alpha y) dy.  $$
Where we used in the last step the substitution $\alpha y=x$. As the equality holds for all Borel sets and $f$ is continuous, we obtain
$$ f(x) = \alpha^2 f(\alpha x). $$
This in turn yields (for $\alpha=x^{-1}$)
$$ f(x) = \frac{f(1)}{x^2}. $$
As the measure cannot be negative, we also have $f(1) \in [0,\infty)$.

Comment: I am familiar with the theorem that if $f,g \in L^1(\lambda)$, then $f = g$ a.e. if and only if $\int_B f = \int_B g$ for all Borel sets. Where are we using continuity?

Comment: To pass from a.e. to everywhere :)

Comment: Hmm, isn't the radon-nikodym derivative $\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}$ the equivalence class of functions $f$ that are equal a.e. and satisfy $d\mu = f d\lambda$? So it would be enough to show $f(x) = f(1)/x^2$ for a.e. $x \in (0,\infty)$. I think continuity needs to be used elsewhere.

Comment: If you want to make a statement $\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}(x)= g(x)$ for all $x$, then you have to impose some condition that allows you to make sense of $\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}(x)$. As you say, it is a priori only defined a.e.

Comment: Otherwise, I could simply change the Radon-Nikodym derivative at $x=5$. This would still be a Radon-Nikody derivative, however, neither continuous, nor would it satisfy the equality you want.

Comment: This is really nice :)

Comment: @h3fr43nd Thank you very much :) In fact I also like the question very much (and if I was to teach a class on measure theory I would put that as an exercise)